# Using Python and Regex get last occurrence and remaining part

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use python and regex to get the last set of integers in a filename (string) Which the method does what i need, however I want to also return the inverse or remaining parts of the regex. How can i do that?

Here is the regex `([0-9]+|#+)(?!.*([0-9]+|#+))`

```
import re

values = [
    'image.0001',
    'image###',
    '###image###',
    'image001',
    'image_001',
    '001',
    '0001.image',
    '001image',
    '001_image',
    'image',
    '01_image01',
    '03_image01',
]

pattern = '([0-9]+|#+|@+)'
regex = '{0}(?!.*{0})'.format(pattern)

for v in values:
    result = re.search(regex, v)
    if result:
        print result.groups()
```

Currently it is returning.... `('01', None)` I'd like it to return something like `('image', '0001')`

**Updated**

Optionally is there a way to split the strings by groups of numbers...for example

```
'image.0001' > ['image.', '0001']
'image###' > ['image', '###']
'###image###' > ['###', 'image', '###']
'image001' > ['image', '001']
'image_001' > ['image_', '001']
'001' > ['001']
'0001.image' > ['0001', '.image']
'001image' > ['001', 'image']
'001_image' > ['001', '_image']
'image' > ['image']
'01_image01' > ['01', '_image', '01']
'03_image01' > ['03', '_image', '01']
```

Comment: Have you tried with `re.findall(...)` ? See https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall

Comment: What are the expected outputs for `0001.image`, `001image`, `001_image` and `image`?

Comment: that's a good question, is there a way for me to return a dict that returns known parts like prefix = all bits and num = last digit occurence?

Comment: check below. You just need to sub all non-letter and all non-numbers to have either one or the other. In what I answered I followed your "last digit" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Use

```py
re.findall(r'\d+|#+|@+|[^#@\d]+', v)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/XAleJ0/2).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  @+                       '@' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^#@\d]+                 any character except: '#', '@', digits (0-
                           9) (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
```

ORIGINAL:
Use `re.split`, add capturing group to keep captured part inside the result:

```py
import re

values = [
    'image.0001',
    'image###',
    '###image###',
    'image001',
    'image_001',
    '001',
    '0001.image',
    '001image',
    '001_image',
    'image',
    '01_image01',
    '03_image01',
]

pattern = '[0-9]+|#+|@+'
regex = re.compile(r'({0})(?!.*(?:{0}))'.format(pattern))
for v in values:
    print(regex.split(v))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##XZDRCsIgGIXvfQrDC7WVOLpqEOs9xhgjbAnbFGejaD27mS1w8@qc7/we8ddPe1P9wTnZaWUsNAKAsW7vYoAnWADoD5Zd3QjGOU/xLiIIob/3co2CX1@pIrCQPGVhIArXvlqAZTqHUeMhIiUAurZWmN7/CRd8fyyTCSXTOcHAiEY8PDaCXVSnZSuIweTF35TkG7YlefbVFLOrMl1tyVxEKfAAjlD28LeuLDysjewtCaVs0K20ZKTUuQ8)

**Results**:

```py
['image.', '0001', '']
['image', '###', '']
['###image', '###', '']
['image', '001', '']
['image_', '001', '']
['', '001', '']
['', '0001', '.image']
['', '001', 'image']
['', '001', '_image']
['image']
['01_image', '01', '']
['03_image', '01', '']
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/XAleJ0/1).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @+                       '@' (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-9]+                   any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @+                       '@' (1 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Is there a way to simply split the string by consecutive numbers? That may work better to avoid the random empty parts of the list

Comment: @JokerMartini Not sure what you mean. Removing empty items is easy, `list(filter(None, result))`.

Comment: I've update the question above to show what i mean. Your' solution is on the right track for what im doing but now seeing it in action i think the updated question would provide a better solution

Comment: How do i modifier it to split not just numbers and words but also `#+|@+` like i have above in my code

Comment: @JokerMartini `re.findall(r'\d+|#+|@+|[^#@\d]+', v)`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

values = [
    'image.0001',
    'image###',
    '###image###',
    'image001',
    'image_001',
    '001',
    '0001.image',
    '001image',
    '001_image',
    'image',
    '01_image01',
    '03_image01',
]

for v in values:
    print (re.sub(r"[^A-Za-z]+","",v), end = " ")
    print (re.sub(r"(.+[_.]){0,1}[^0-9]+","",v))
```

Output:

```
image 0001
image 
image 
image 001
image 001
 001
image 
image 001
image 
image 
image 01
image 01
```

Comment: last occurrence. So '0001.image', should still return a number

Comment: You you don't want "the last set of integers in a filename "

Comment: I want the last occurrence.  I'll update question